# WPF Textbox flickering

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a WPF application. I would like to change the visibility of a grid in the WPF application by clicking on a textbox. When I change the visibility of the grid the textbox is flickering.

What is the reason for the flickering? How can I avoid the flickering?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ChangeVisibility.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ChangeVisbility" ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF646464"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,4,5,0"/>
            <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextRenderingMode" Value="Grayscale"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF9B9B9B"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid Name="Grid1" Width="256" Height="128" Background="#FFFFFFFF">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Text="Input" MouseUp="Change" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource TextBox}"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Name="Grid2" Width="256" Height="128" Background="#FFFFFFFF">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Text="Output" MouseUp="Change" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource TextBox}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace ChangeVisibility
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Change(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Grid1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                Grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Grid2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                Grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                Grid2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could shorten the `Change` code slightly by doing `var g1Visibility = Grid1.Visibility; Grid1.Visibility = Grid2.Visibility; Grid2.Visibility = g1Visibility;`

Comment: I tried the code. But unfortunately the textbox is still flickering.

Comment: Yeah, it was not going to solve that problem, just a shorter way of writing it.

Comment: Have you ever thought of using Binding and a converter? Clicking on a `TextBox` is a rather unusual case, can you use a Button instead? If not, then use `interaction` from Blend SDK and utilise `EventToCommand` Binding.

Comment: I use a textbox instead of a button to easily achieve a flat design. When I use a button and I change the visibility of the grid the button is also flickering. How do I realize the change of visibility by using binding and a converter in code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, its because of your text box style . As you can see , you are changing background color on mouse hover , as soon as visibility code fires, mouse position changes and background color will change again .

try to set background color for "IsMouseOver= False" as well

```
 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF9B9B9B"/>
  </Trigger>
```

Comment: The textbox should have a mouseover effect. Is there a solution to keep the mouseover effect?